# Split python regex code into multiple lines

Tags: python, regex

The following code is working fine

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import re

preflist = 'ip prefix-list PL_FROM_7600 seq 255 permit 192.168.0.0/15 ge 20 le 25'
mymatch = re.search(r'(ip prefix-list) (?P<prefname>\w+) (?P<prefseq>seq \d+) (permit|deny)', preflist)

print(mymatch)

if mymatch is not None:
    print(mymatch.group('prefname'))
    print(mymatch.group('prefseq'))
```

and print the following which prove that my regex is working fine:

```
[user@serv:14:14:58~/scripts]$ ./retest.py
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 42), match='ip prefix-list PL_FROM_7600 seq 255 permit'>

PL_FROM_7600

seq 255
```

So now I am trying to split this into multiple lines (for [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)  compliance of [maximum 72 characters per line](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length)) using `re.VERBOSE` but keep getting errors. I have tried pretty much all combination including `re.compile` and using raw or not.

Here is an example that I have tried directly from the python console;

```
>>> preflist = 'ip prefix-list PL_FROM_7600 seq 255 permit 192.168.0.0/15 ge 20 le 25'

>>> myregex = re.compile(r'''
... (ip prefix-list)
... (?P<prefname>\w+)
... (?P<prefseq>seq \d+)
... (permit|deny)
... ''', re.VERBOSE)

>>> myregex
re.compile('\n(ip prefix-list)\n(?P<prefname>\\w+)\n(?P<prefseq>seq \\d+)\n(permit|deny)\n', re.VERBOSE)

>>> x = myregex.search(preflist)
>>> x
>>> print(x)
None
```

Another example that I have tried...

```
>>> mypattern ='''
... (ip prefix-list)
... (\s?P<prefname>\w+)
... (\s?P<prefseq>seq \d+)
... (\spermit|deny)
... '''

>>> mypattern
'\n(ip prefix-list)\n(\\s?P<prefname>\\w+)\n(\\s?P<prefseq>seq \\d+)\n(\\spermit|deny)\n'

>>> preflist = 'ip prefix-list PL_FROM_7600 seq 255 permit 192.168.0.0/15 ge 20 le 25'
>>> preflist
'ip prefix-list PL_FROM_7600 seq 255 permit 192.168.0.0/15 ge 20 le 25'


>>> mymatch = re.search(mypattern, preflist,re.VERBOSE)

>>> mymatch
>>> print(mymatch)
None
>>>
```

Comment: You have literal spaces inside the pattern, replace them with `\s` or `\s+` (see `seq \d+`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to account for spaces in your pattern. All literal spaces not inside character classes are ignored. You can match whitespace with `\s+` (1 or more whitespace) or with `[ ]+` (to match 1+ literal spaces).

I suggest sticking to `\s` since it is the only more-or-less portable solution (in Java free space mode, spaces are ignored even inside character classes).

```
(ip\s+prefix-list)\s+
(?P<prefname>\w+)\s+
(?P<prefseq>seq\s+\d+)\s+
(permit|deny)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fX6hM2/1) and a [Python code demo](https://ideone.com/ar02mo):

```
import re
myregex = re.compile(r'''
(ip\s+prefix-list)\s+
(?P<prefname>\w+)\s+
(?P<prefseq>seq\s+\d+)\s+
(permit|deny)
''', re.VERBOSE)
preflist = 'ip prefix-list PL_FROM_7600 seq 255 permit 192.168.0.0/15 ge 20 le 25'
mymatch = myregex.search(preflist)
print(mymatch)
# => <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 42), match='ip prefix-list PL_FROM_7600 seq 255 permit'>
```

Comment: Thanks this is working, I did try '\s' this morning without the '+' since I need only one space but put it only after each sub-statement after the parenthesis. I didn't realized that I should use it as well inside the parenthesis. Can you please replace IP address in your code with 192.168.0.0/15 for privacy reason? I forgot to do it before posting. I have updated my original post accrodingly.

Comment: regex101 does not fetch share URLs, I will update once it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using re.VERBOSE by splitting you original regular expression:

```
mymatch = re.search(r'(ip prefix-list) ' # comment
                 '(?P<prefname>\w+) ' # some text
                 '(?P<prefseq>seq \d+) ' # more comments
                 '(permit|deny)'
                 , preflist)
```

It works well with you first example.